# Magento admin categories not displaying correct

Tags: magento-1.7

Hi so I have this magento installation going. I have a problem when using the admin interface for categories. In the beginning everything works just fine, but at a random time after my clean install, the manage categories displays like this:

[image]

Any ideas why it does this? I can't add any categories after this error occurs.

Comment: Running the Chrome Resources i can see that it returns a fatal error:
`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget::getrowurl() in <b>/var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php</b> on line <b>1674</b><br />`

Comment: I found the solution on this site:

..app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php on line 1607

I tried to find out the error reason then I got my solution. And solution is :

Go To app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php

Search function getRowUrl in the file.

public function getRowUrl($item)
{
$res = parent::getRowUrl($item);
return ($res ? $res : '#');
}
Replace this function with below function:

public function getRowUrl($item)
{
$res = parent::getUrl($item);
return ($res ? $res : '#');
}